# WPF - How to refresh a view in a ContentControl content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, view, refresh

Im a beginner in c# and i want to refresh a view in a ContentControl of my MainWindow
My script is working but when a relaycommand is changing, i must to change view and turn back to the wanted view manually.

**Exemple :** [Video Exemple](https://youtu.be/Qq1G6M1iHU4)

Thanks a lot for your help

--

**My MainWindow XAML window:**

```
<Window x:Class="BS_Core.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BS_Core"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:BS_Core.MVVM.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="BS Core" Height="800" Width="1300"
        WindowStyle="none"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        MouseDown="Window_MouseDown"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Background="Transparent"
        AllowsTransparency="true" Icon="Logo-w.png">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

His ContentControl :

```
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="10,0,10,10"
                            Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/>
<ContentControl Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Margin="10,0,10,10"
                            Content="{Binding CurrentServersView}"/>
```

**MainViewModel C#:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using BS_Core.Core;

namespace BS_Core.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public RelayCommand HomeViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand FivemViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand MinecraftViewCommand { get; set; }
        public RelayCommand RustViewCommand { get; set; }

        public HomeViewModel HomeVM { get; set; }
        public FivemViewModel FivemVM { get; set; }
        public MinecraftViewModel MinecraftVM { get; set; }
        public RustViewModel RustVM { get; set; }


        private object _currentView;

        public object CurrentView
        {
            get { return _currentView; }
            set
            {
                _currentView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        //-------------------------------

        public ServersHomeViewModel ServersHomeVM { get; set; }
        public NoServersViewModel NoServersVM { get; set; }

        public ServersFivemViewModel ServersFivemVM { get; set; }

        private object _currentServersView;

        public object CurrentServersView
        {
            get { return _currentServersView; }
            set
            {
                _currentServersView = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }


        }



        //-------------------------------


        public MainViewModel()
        {


            HomeVM = new HomeViewModel();
            FivemVM = new FivemViewModel();
            MinecraftVM = new MinecraftViewModel();
            RustVM = new RustViewModel();


            ServersHomeVM = new ServersHomeViewModel();
            NoServersVM = new NoServersViewModel();
            ServersFivemVM = new ServersFivemViewModel();

            CurrentView = HomeVM;
            CurrentServersView = ServersHomeVM;

            HomeViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = HomeVM;
                CurrentServersView = ServersHomeVM;
            });


            string roaming = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);


            FivemViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(roaming + "/BSCore/FiveM"))
                {
                    CurrentView = FivemVM;
                    CurrentServersView = NoServersVM;
                }
                else
                {
                    CurrentView = FivemVM;
                    CurrentServersView = ServersFivemVM;
                }

            });

            MinecraftViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = MinecraftVM;
                CurrentServersView = NoServersVM;
            });

            RustViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {
                CurrentView = RustVM;
                CurrentServersView = NoServersVM;
            });

        }


    }


}
```

**App.XAML :**

```
<Application x:Class="BS_Core.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BS_Core"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:BS_Core.MVVM.ViewModel"
             xmlns:view="clr-namespace:BS_Core.MVVM.View" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/MenuButtonTheme.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/TextBoxTheme.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Icons.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:HomeViewModel}">
                <view:HomeView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:FivemViewModel}">
                <view:FivemView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:MinecraftViewModel}">
                <view:MinecraftView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:RustViewModel}">
                <view:RustView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ServersHomeViewModel}">
                <view:ServersHomeView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:NoServersViewModel}">
                <view:NoServersView/>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ServersFivemViewModel}">
                <view:ServersFivemView/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**RelayCommand C# :**

```
namespace BS_Core.Core
{
    class RelayCommand : ICommand
    {
        private Action<object> _execute;
        private Func<object, bool> _canExecute;

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _execute(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

**ObservableObject C# :**

```
namespace BS_Core.Core
{
    class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. When the command is changing? Cna you describe the scenario a bit better please? Generally, assigning a new value to the CurrentView and CurrentServersView will raise the PropertyChanged event and trigger the data binding to this property to update.

Comment: that's why i don't understand PropertyChanged is supposed to trigger the data binding to this property to update. I used this code :

`FivemViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
            {if (!Directory.Exists(roaming + "/BSCore/FiveM"))
                {CurrentView = FivemVM;
                    CurrentServersView = NoServersVM;
}else{
                    CurrentView = FivemVM;
                    CurrentServersView = ServersFivemVM;}});`

But when a button deletes roaming/BSCore/FiveM folder, the if condition does not update and the view don't change ;( 
thank's for your help ^^

Comment: So command works until you remove the folder that the command checks?? Have you debugged it? Additionally move the `roaming` variable declaration and assignment inside the lamda of the command. Otherwise it will have to capture the complete context!